# How to initialize const data members in initializer list that share common attributes?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

Suppose we have a class `Bar` which has two data members, `a` and `b` respectively pointing to two other objects of type `A`. Within this type `A`, we have a data member `i` that points to an integer.

In the code below, in order to allow the data members of `Bar`, i.e. `a` and `b` to share the same pointer `i`. I have to create another data member inside `Bar` that represent the common pointer `a` and `b` are going to share.

However, I'm wondering if there's any way of sharing the same intermediate pointer `i` when initializing `a` and `b` in the initializer list.

```
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    const shared_ptr<int> i;

    explicit A(const shared_ptr<int> &i): i(i) {}
};

struct Bar {
    const shared_ptr<int> _i;
    const unique_ptr<A> a;
    const unique_ptr<A> b;

    explicit Bar(const int &i):
            _i(make_shared<int>(i)),
            a(make_unique<A>(_i)),
            b(make_unique<A>(_i)) {}
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `A::i` is `public` and is a `shared_ptr`, you can eliminate the need for `Bar::_i` like this:

```cpp
struct Bar {
    const unique_ptr<A> a;
    const unique_ptr<A> b;

    explicit Bar(const int &i):
            a(make_unique<A>(make_shared<int>(i))),
            b(make_unique<A>(a->i)) {}
};
```

If `A::i` is later made `private`, simply make `Bar` be a `friend` of `A`, then it should still work.

With the old code, you could have done this:

```cpp
struct Bar {
    const A* a;
    const A* b;

    explicit Bar(const int &i):
            a(new A(new int(i))),
            b(new A(a->i)) {}
};
```

But you would have had a management problem in deciding who is responsible for freeing the `int*`. With `shared_ptr`, you don't have to worry about that.